# ROUND function in ODBC

Tags: sql, odbc

I am working on a third-party custom flat file DB that I access through ODBC and the ROUND function is throwing errors always.
Is there a function that can do rounding in ODBC?
An example that throws an error:

`SELECT AUDIT_SPLIT.ACCOUNT_REF, ROUND(SUM(AUDIT_SPLIT.GROSS_AMOUNT), 2) FROM AUDIT_SPLIT GROUP BY AUDIT_SPLIT.ACCOUNT_REF`

Though Excel the error is "Column not found"

Comment: You could try the ODBC style `{fn ROUND(SUM(AUDIT_SPLIT.GROSS_AMOUNT), 2)}`.

Comment: What do you mean by "ODBC style" pls? Just add {fn } around?

Comment: Sometimes you get access to additional functions this way.

Comment: Does that SQL run if you remove the ROUND function? The error is suggesting that a column doesn’t exist, not that there is an issue with the ROUND function

Comment: @NickW it does run without the ROUND. I understand your point.

Comment: @jarlh I have tried adding it as you wrote and the same error comes up running it through Excel

Answer (score 1):

Is your flat file something like a csv, a delimited text file or a fixed length file?
In this case I will suggest to check for the last line is not empty.
If the file ends with a cr/lf a new line is added and it is filled with nulls.

Also, from which client are you running the query? You have not given a name to `ROUND()` column, maybe you need it.

So I will try something like this:

```
SELECT A.ACCOUNT_REF, ROUND(SUM(A.GROSS_AMOUNT), 2) AS GROSS_AMOUNT_SUM
FROM AUDIT_SPLIT A
WHERE A.ACCOUNT_REF IS NOT NULL AND A.GROSS_AMOUNT IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY A.ACCOUNT_REF
```

**UPDATE**

Maybe the problem is related to the comma present in `ROUND` function, because it is interpreted as a column separator, you can avoid it using `ODBC` escape clause `{fn ROUND()}` (as suggested by [jarlh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74927027/round-function-in-odbc/74992186?noredirect=1#comment132225144_74927027) in his comment), and to be sure and clear I will try to split the `SUM()` and the `ROUND()` in this way:

```
SELECT S.ACCOUNT_REF, {fn ROUND(S.GROSS_AMOUNT_SUM, 2)} AS ROUNDED_SUM
FROM (
    SELECT A.ACCOUNT_REF, SUM(A.GROSS_AMOUNT) AS GROSS_AMOUNT_SUM
    FROM AUDIT_SPLIT AS A
    WHERE A.ACCOUNT_REF IS NOT NULL AND A.GROSS_AMOUNT IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY A.ACCOUNT_REF
) AS S
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Running like this through Excel gives Column not found error. When I remove the ROUND it works fine. So the ROUND command is definitely not supported. And It's really bad news for me.

Comment: `ROUND` function **IS** supported by `ODBC`, please show example for your db file, the odbc driver used and its version.

Comment: Thank you! I am working against Sage 50 database. Sage 50 is an accounting software. And to test their data you'd need to install it. So I'm thinking that they have a different, non-standard, ODBC driver for their connection. In fact, when going through Excel, I select SageLine50v28 as a Data Source Name (DSN) from the drop down.

Answer (score 1):

So I will try something like this:

SELECT A.ACCOUNT_REF, ROUND(SUM(A.GROSS_AMOUNT), 2)  GROSS_AMOUNT_SUM
FROM AUDIT_SPLIT A
WHERE A.ACCOUNT_REF IS NOT NULL AND A.GROSS_AMOUNT IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 1

Comment: 1) Lets not use CAPS while writing the answers.
2) If your answer includes a code snippet then use the code formatting block
3) Try to explain your logic; how it is going to work